# issues before update flutter version: rm_navigator

Tags: flutter, flutter-update

After doing the flutter update yesterday, my project stopped compiling, throwing the following error message, I don't understand what it could be or what changes should be made.

Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
navigation_builder.dart:701
semanticsDismissible: semanticsDismissible,

HELP!!!!

The only way I was able to continue working currently was to go back to the previous version of flutter, but I can't find any information on that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.